# Cookie Option is request.get()

Tags: python

I am not experienced in web development, and trying to use requests.get to get some authenticated data. So far the internet appears to tell me to just do it, and i think i am formatting it wrong, but unsure how. After some trial and error, i was able to grab my cookie for the website. The following is some a made up version of what i grabbed with similar formating.

```
cookie = "s:abcDEfGHIJ12k34LMNopqRst5UvW-6xy.ZAbCd/eFGhi7j8KlmnoPqrstUvWXYZ90a1BCDE2fGH3"
```

Then, in python, i am trying to send a request. Following is a bit more pseudo code for what i am doing

```
r = requests.get('https://www.website.com/api/getData', cookies={"connect.sid": cookie})
```

After all this, the site keeps sending me a 400 error. Wondering if you guys had any idea if I am  putting in the wrong cookie/part of cookie. If everything looks right and it is probably the site at fault, or what.

Comment: shouldn't it be header than cookie ?

Comment: Changing cookies to headers doesn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: `requests.get('https://www.website.com/api/getData', cookies=cookie)` isn't enough? Also, do you need any additional json body on your call? Perhaps error 400 could be something missing, but it really depends on how your website/API works

Comment: I found two different repos on github that seemed to just use this to to interact with it. Sent email's to the authors, but yeah, i'll reach out if it is website dependent then.

Comment: As per the official [python requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) the syntax seems to be right. Maybe the cookie that you are sending is not right. What is the response status code? 403?

Comment: Straight up 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabbed a wireshark capture, and found there were other fields in the cookie that were sent that i had not filled out.

```
_ga
_gid
___gads
```

Filled those out with the relevant values, and it works.